# Transformar un "exec()" de python en str

Tags: python

estoy haciendo unos experimentos en python, me preguntaba si es posible transformar un `exec()` en un string, ejemplo:

```
def prueba():
    print("hola mundo")
var = exec("prueba()")
```

la idea es que la variable "var" tenga el valor "hola mundo", la verdad es que no creo que siquiera sea posible pero espero equivocarme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es posible directamente por una razón muy simple, **`prueba` no retorna "nada"**, la función se limita a imprimir la cadena por la salida estándar y a retornar `None` (toda función/método retorna `None` por defecto). Igual que si haces:

```
>>> var = prueba()
```

`var` es `None`, que es lo que retorna la función y no `"hola mundo"`.

Por otro lado, **`exec` siempre retorna `None`**, descartando cualquier retorno resultado de ejecutar el código recibido, pero puedes realizar una asignación en la cadena que le pasas sin problemas, mientras sea código Python válido `exec` hace la "magia", muy oscura y peligrosa por cierto... :)

```
def prueba():
    return("hola mundo")
exec("var = prueba()")

print(var)
```

o usar `eval`, que solo permite una expresión (si lo que se le pasa es una cadena) a diferencia de `exec` pero que, por otro lado, retorna el resultado de su evaluación:

```
def prueba():
    return("hola mundo")
var = eval("prueba()")

print(var)
```